# NWL NX Angular Jest tests are reporting "unable to find describe" errors

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, tsconfig, angular-test

Does anyone know why my Angular Jest Tests are reporting:
`error TS2593: Cannot find name 'describe’.`  ??

I have an NWL NX Workspace running an Angular App & Multiple Libs.

The tests in all the **Libs** are running fine.
The  tests in the **App** are all reporting this error.
I have not edited the config - so these should be the config from the NX setup.
How do I fix this?? Any ideas?

App TsConfigs:
// tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types" : ["node"],
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.editor.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

// tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types" : ["node"],
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"]
}
```

// tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test-setup.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this did not work for me:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types" : ["node", "jest"],
  },
```

But this did: ???

```
"compilerOptions": {
  },
```

No Idea why though.